# Zip File Upload using Kudu REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, file-upload, kudu

I am trying to upload an approx. 10.5 MBs zip file to my Azure website from Powershell using the following url:
"https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"

Here's the sample code:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -DisableKeepAlive -Method PUT -InFile $zipPackagePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data";
```

My upload speed is a tad below 1 Mbps and it takes upto 5 mins ore more for the file transfer to be complete.
From the same machine, when I upload the zip file using Kudu console (by dropping it onto the surface for extracting zip files), it uploads fine as well as is extracted as expected.

However when using PowerShell, the upload aborts after ~1 - 2 mins. The error I get is:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Inner Exception for the same is: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection:

`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

I tried increasing the timeout on the request to as high a 36000 seconds (10 hours), tried disabling Keep-alive on the web request and other such tricks. None succeeded. I tried uploading a 100 KB zip file using Powershell and it went smoothly and was extracted successfully by Kudu too.

So my question now is, what do I need to do to enable larger file uploads using Kudu Rest API on a comparatively slower connection.
Is this related to request limits / max upload sizes on Kudu's side? If yes, where can I increase max upload size / request length limit for my Kudu instance of Azure web app.
If this could be something else, I would appreciate all insights.

Comment: We've had reports before of zip API having issues specifically when using PowerShell, but working fine through other clients like curl. e.g. see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1448

Comment: Why not upload files via Azure WebJob?

Comment: Hi @DavidEbbo, I tried uploading via a custom .Net console application invoked via command-line (no powershell), and I receive the exact same error forcing me now to assume this is something with Kudu itself. Any more insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To isolate, see if it repros when uploading via different web app. And also try with a different zip of similar size. E.g. Create a zip using the Windows shell by right clicking a folder.